# Get product outside magento directory without knowing ID

Tags: php, magento

I've got a CSV full of SKU's that I need to load outside the Magento directory to make some changes.

So far I have this:

```
require_once('bla/bla/../../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(15186);
$productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('thatsku');
$product2->load($productid);
var_dump($product1);
var_dump($product2);
```

In this case, $product1 returns the product as expected, but $product2 returns `bool(false)`.
Same thing happens when I try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
var_dump ($_product);
```

$product also returns as `bool(false)` here.

Any idea on what's going on?

EDIT: Sorry I'm dumb. There was no SKU in the database even thought I could've sweared I added it for testing sake. This code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I'm dumb. There was no SKU in the database even thought I could've sweared I added it for testing sake. This code works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
print_r($product);
```

sometimes var_dump doesn't seem to trigger the property getters so they are shown as null

Comment: Oh damn. Could have sweared I added it for testing sake. Went to double check and it wasn't there. Not sure what happened but that was a the problem. I feel dumb now! Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Always welcome..I have tried your code in my local server. I already faced this problem.. So I just tried with print_r() ..It working fine ..

Answer (score 1):

here i can give you one alternate solution is it would work for you

create function to get product id from SKU so that would be better

```
function getProductId($sku)
{

    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    static $product_ids;
    if (is_object($sku)) {
        $sku = $sku->asArray();
    }
    if (empty($product_ids)) {
        $skus = $write->query('select sku, entity_id from `catalog_product_entity` where type_id="simple"');
        foreach ($skus->fetchAll() as $data) {
            $product_ids[$data['sku']] = $data['entity_id'];
        }
        unset($skus);
        unset($data);
    }
    return isset($product_ids[$sku]) ? $product_ids[$sku] : '';
}
```

will return product id and then you can easily find with below code

```
$id = getProductId('YOUR SKU GOES HERE');

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

hope this will sure help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the function, it works indeed. I'll be using it in the future for sure. My problem was different though, you can see the edit.